# webkit - SVG animation transform persists after it shouldn't

Tags: css, svg

There's a weird behavior in Chrome where animation last frame persists after there should be no more animation. This works good in Firefox.

*(Try hovering the circle then hover-out)*

[**Demo playground**](https://jsbin.com/coyitu/edit?html,css,output)

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

@keyframes foo {
  50% { transform: scale(2); }
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}

circle:hover { animation: 2s foo infinite; }

.point {
  stroke-width: 1px;
  stroke-opacity: .2;
  fill-opacity: .5;
  transition-property: opacity, fill;
  fill: red;
  stroke: red;
}

.point.stroke {
  fill-opacity: .3;
}
```

```html
<svg>
    <g  transform="translate(65, 70)">
       <circle class="point stroke" r="25"/>
       <circle class="point" r="25"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Don't quite understand. The animation is an infinite animation and so it keeps repeating the animation and when I hover out, it goes to original state. Using Chrome 51.0.2704.4 dev-m.

Comment: @Harry - what browser? it doesn't do that for me and my buddy here tested on 3 computers (windows / Chrome). it is infinite as long as you hover the circle, and should show the original state once hovering-out.

Comment: Sticks for me in Chrome 50

Comment: Interesting then maybe it was bug which they've addressed.

Comment: I can reproduce the bug in the jsbin link you sent. However in the SO playground you edited I cannot. The answer must be in the different CSS code.

Comment: @SideriteZackwehdex - you sure? try hovering and focus-out a few times.  it is identical in terms of logic. I only removed unnecessary things. I will update the demo as well.

Comment: I can't make the animation continue after I move the mouse in the SO page. I tried. In the other I have to move the mouse really fast over and out for it to stop. Also, on the SO page the circle is more opaque.

Comment: The same behavior for me in both the snippet and the playground. Both stop as soon as I hover out of the hit area (note that in the playground the hit area is large due to the height on the `svg`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

putting `transform:scale(1)` as the default CSS for the `.stroke` seems to solve this

Answer (score 0):

To fix your problem, give the circle a default transform that it should go back to when the hover state finishes. For example:

```
.point {
   ...
   transform: scale(1);
}
```

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

@keyframes foo {
  50% { transform: scale(2); }
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}

circle:hover { animation: 2s foo infinite; }

.point {
  stroke-width: 1px;
  stroke-opacity: .2;
  fill-opacity: .5;
  fill: red;
  stroke: red;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.point.stroke {
  fill-opacity: .3;
}
```

```html
<svg>
    <g  transform="translate(65, 70)">
       <circle class="point stroke" r="25"/>
       <circle class="point" r="25"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: haha I've discovered that 5 minuets ago :) so strange it doesn't accept `none` as the value for `transform`. it does accept this for non-svg elements.. Thanks for taking the time to help with this bizarre bug.